# Predicting recurrent calendar events : Finding the next weekday and next day from a patterned interval

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working on a project to create a scheduling calendar that calculates the next ten appointments for a given unit based on the last appointment date retrieved from the "Unit Log." My goal is to calculate these appointments using one of three different methods, but only one method should be applied at a time. The three options are:

- Fixed Interval: Schedule the next appointments at a fixed interval of
  days, such as every 7 days. (this one already works)
- Patterned Interval: Schedule the appointments using a repeating
  pattern of days, such as 2 days, then 2 days, then 1 day, and then
  repeat this pattern.
- Specific Weekdays: Schedule the appointments on the next available
  dates that match specified weekdays, such as only on    Mondays and
  Fridays.

How can I create a flexible and efficient formula that allows me to choose one of these methods at a time and accurately calculates the next ten appointments based on the selected method?

[Here's the Spreadhsheet that I'm trying to implement it](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JLUj3S_8SOIGNY1TRTYNbAbyUotthVLOV775Y06qbpg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you **manually** enter the expected output for you test scenarios?! Does `Client` and `Unit` need not be a part of the current `filter` formula you have in the sheet; right now only `building` seems to be tallied b/w *Calendar* and *Unit Log* tabs...

Comment: @rockinfreakshow, Hi, yes, sorry for not being clear enough. It's better explained now, and made a a lot of examples. Thanks!

Comment: For third scenario (Monday, Friday), the 1st appointment jumps from *last appointment date* i.e., `Mon, 14 Aug` to `Mon, 21 Aug`. Is `Fri, 18 Aug` supposed to be skipped?!

Comment: @rockinfreakshow, No it was a mistake, sorry. I fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's [one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JLUj3S_8SOIGNY1TRTYNbAbyUotthVLOV775Y06qbpg/edit#gid=1279274500) added to your sheet. Please do test it out with quite a few scenarios to make sure its holdin' up:*

```js
=map(A2:A,B2:B,C2:C,D2:D,E2:E,lambda(a,b,c,d,e,if(counta(a,b,c,d,e)<4,,ifna(let(Σ,max(filter('Unit Log_2'!A:A,'Unit Log_2'!B:B=a,'Unit Log_2'!C:C=b,'Unit Log_2'!D:D=c,not('Unit Log_2'!I:I),'Unit Log_2'!A:A<today())),
     if(len(d),scan(Σ,array_constrain(split(rept(substitute(d," ",)&",",10),","),1,10),lambda(a,c,a+c)),
     if(len(e),let(Λ,sequence(77,1,Σ+1),array_constrain(torow(filter(Λ,regexmatch(text(Λ,"dddd"),regexreplace(proper(e),",\s*","|")))),1,10)),))),"--"))))
```

`Disclaimer`: *some of your `Unit Log` Column_A dates are valid **date-types** and some aren't which you might need to check upon. I used a [copy of that tab](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JLUj3S_8SOIGNY1TRTYNbAbyUotthVLOV775Y06qbpg/edit#gid=1693642658) with the dates fixed to serve the purpose*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for noting about the dates! And the formula works way better then I was hoping for. Thanks!